# How to setup Magento to get products using REST

Tags: php, magento, rest, magento-1.7

I don't know what urls to use to get products using REST in magento.
I'm using tutorials:

http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/configure-magento-rest-and-oauth-settings/

and

http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/consuming-magento-rest-zend_oauth_consumer/

Problem is that my urls are in this format:
http://magento.loc/magento/index.php/admin/index

but in these tutorials there is no index.php.

In my code it looks:

```
    $params = array(
        'siteUrl' => 'http://magento.loc/magento/index.php/oauth',
        'requestTokenUrl' => 'http://magento.loc/magento/index.php/oauth/initiate',
        'accessTokenUrl' => 'http://magento.loc/magento/index.php/oauth/token',
        'authorizeUrl' => 'http://magento.loc/magento/index.php/admin/oAuth_authorize',
        'consumerKey' => '381ywp8r50hxzjw62srozns7pbzzhzrn',
        'consumerSecret' => 'zhjo3nciz9qj3dv6ts6g4bttixg0dqy9',
        'callbackUrl' => 'http://magento.loc/magento/index.php/genr        
                           /test/callback',

    );
```

And at the bottom:
$restClient->setUri('http://magento.loc/magento/index.php/api/rest/products');

Using this configuration i get no results when I enter:

```
      http://magento.loc/magento/index.php/genre/test/index
```

in browser URL, 
I get authorize application question, and after I press authorize, i get page that returns code 200,
but no products are return ( when printing json response it say 404 not found)

Comment: You have a plus ',' in your last key, inside params.. and remove the newline in the callbackurl.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution:

```
 'siteUrl' => 'http://magento.loc/magento/oauth',
 'requestTokenUrl' => 'http://magento.loc/magento/oauth/initiate',
 'accessTokenUrl' => 'http://magento.loc/magento/oauth/token',
 'authorizeUrl' => 'http://magento.loc/magento/admin/oAuth_authorize', 
 'consumerKey' => '381ywp8r50hxzjw62srozns7pbzzhzrn',
 'consumerSecret' => 'zhjo3nciz9qj3dv6ts6g4bttixg0dqy9',
 'callbackUrl' => 'http://magento.loc/magento/genre/test/callback'
```

and after :

```
 $restClient->setUri('http://magento.loc/magento/api/rest/products');
```

Issue was that I didn't assign role for current logged admin user in Magento.
System > Permission > Users > and check rest role for admin user.
There is no need to write /index.php in URL